# CupertinoTextField with Form widget

Tags: flutter, dart

The issue I am having is the onChanged event on the form is not firing when using CupertinoTextField with the Form Widget.  The event is triggered with the TextFormField.

I would like to compare two cupertinoTextFields at the form level as the user is typing.

Comment: can you please add your code because when i tried it works on android emulator.

Comment: yes it works on android fine.  But it will not work on ios.  The Form widget Onchange event is not seeing the changes from the CupertinoTextField on ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much difference between the CupertinoTextField and material's TextField when used on an iOS device (which you can force a target os). Both can be styled but the TextField has the added bonus of using materialTextSelection tools when used on android. Therefore, using the convenience class of TextFormField is probably the simplest solution for you.

Comment: An alternative is to copy TextFormField class into your own class, then use a CupertinoTextField in place of the TextField that flutter defaults to. Again, it's probably simpler to just use the TextFormField and style it the way you want.

Comment: I considered this approach, but I like using the platform specific controls where possible.

Comment: Right, and TextField uses the device controls depending on which target os is running.

Comment: This I did not know.  Thank for the valuable information.